# TCP sampler with multiple packet in response

Tags: jmeter

I am sending request as TCP sampler. In response I am sending two response in two different packet on socket. So both have same end of line("E"). So its stop reading at first response. I want to read second also. Please help to read second response also.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter by default uses read method of TCPClientImpl class while reading response. So have a look at this class at
https://github.com/udomsak/JMeter/blob/master/src/protocol/tcp/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPClientImpl.java

Write your own class by extending TCPClientImpl and overwrite read method according to your logic and  the add this jar in your Jmeter lib folder and restart your Jmeter.